# Can't merge a list using addAll method in Jmeter's BeanShell

Tags: java, list, jmeter, beanshell

Trying to merge a list using addAll method in Jmeter's BeanShell, but the BeanShellInterpreter said the method not found.

I tried to merge 2 lists using the tutorial from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/merge-two-lists-in-java).

## The list that I want to merge, looks like this:

1. carID_1=[307,308,304]
2. carID_2=[305]
3. carID_3=[306]

## And here's the code I wrote:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<Integer> allCarID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numOfCarID = vars.get("carID_matchNr"); //contains the number of list used for looping
int numOfCarID = Integer.parseInt(numOfCarID);

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfCarID; i++){
    x = vars.get("carID_"+i);
    allCarID.addAll(x);
}

log.info("All Car: " + allCarID);
```

When I try to run the code, it gives me an error said that `Encountered "=" at line 4, column 25.`. After some research, I try to change the code to `List allCarID = new ArrayList();` and code successfully reached the addAll method.

It show an error like this:
`Error in method invocation: Method addAll( java.lang.String ) not found in class'java.util.ArrayList'`.

Try to change `addAll`to 'add', the code executed successfully and didn't show an error, but the result I wanted was different.

What I want is a list `[307,308,304,305,306]`, but I got a `[[307,308,304], [305], [306]]` instead.

Any kind of help is very helpful, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're trying to pass a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to the [ArrayList.addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) function, it won't work as the function expects a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating
3. The code you wrote doesn't compile so I fail to see how did you get this output

If you have these `carID_1=[307,308,304]` stored as Strings you could do something like:

```
vars.put('carID_1', '[307,308,304]')
vars.put('carID_2', '[305]')
vars.put('carID_3', '[306]')
vars.put("carID_matchNr", "3")

List<Integer> allCarID = new ArrayList<Integer>();

1.upto((vars.get('carID_matchNr') as int), {
    def carIDs = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('carID_' + it))
    allCarID.addAll(carIDs)
})

log.info('All Car: ' + allCarID)
```

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hi, it's working. Got this as a result `JSR223 PostProcessor: All Car: [283, 284]`.  I slightly modified the syntax with the one suggested by @lucas-nguyen-17 , for the declaration of the list and for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from `vars.get("carID_"+i)`, it will return String instead of List. Therefore, use `vars.getObject("carID_"+i)` and `flatten()` of groovy methods will help you.

1. Use JSR223
2. Choose language: groovy
3. Sample code as below:

```
vars.putObject("carID_1", [307,308,304])
vars.putObject("carID_2", [305])
vars.putObject("carID_3", [306])

def allCarID = []

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    def x = vars.getObject("carID_"+i)
    allCarID.add(x)
}

allCarID = allCarID.flatten()

log.info("All Car: " + allCarID)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've tried the solutions you've provided, but I still get the same results `JSR223 PostProcessor: All Car: [[283], [284]]`